# Хочу создать файл миграции Flask, но выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Я только учусь.
Это ссылка на проект на GitHub, чтобы была возможность видеть полную картину.
https://github.com/IanKir/my-Flask-blog

Я хочу выполнить команду в терминале находясь в папке myApp и с активированным виртуальным окружением.
Команда выглядит так:
python manage.py db init
Чтобы создать папку миграции базы данных

При выполнении этой команды выдается ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in 
    from myApp.app import manager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myApp'

Помогите понять, что не так и как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результатом оказалось то,что при импорте не нужно указывать папку myApp.
После того, как из всех импортов я убрал myApp, команда python manage.py db init заработала.